# Does amyone know what type of bonsai tree this is

Tags: trees, bonsai

[image]

I got this tree about a week ago but i dont know what type it is help someone

Comment: I have outside for almost the whole day but i bring it inside at night i about 4 times a day to make sure it good i just got into this bobby so itll be great if you could give me more tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a juniperus procumbens nana. It should be kept outside.

It is quite cold hardy (being able to survive to nearly -30F/-35C), drought tolerant (which means to be careful not to over water), and needs full sun.